# simple way of generating shapes

Tags: c++, c, image, image-processing

I want to generate shapes like the one following (image file e.g. PNG):

[image: example]

I'm looking for  a c / c++ library which will allow me to realize the following algorithm:

The basic algorithm would be:

1. Make circle
2. Partition Circle randomly
3. Fill in one segement
4. Twirl whole shape (see link)
5. Save Image as PNG

[Link: Twirl filter in Photoshop](http://www.entheosweb.com/photoshop/twirl.asp)

I will accept the first answer which lists and links **one library or more** which is will enable me to implement the above algorithm with ease. The library should be light weight if possible.

Comment: Is there anything especially meaningful about these shapes, or will any graphical library do?

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't quite know what you mean. But basically any solution with will do that is suited for a task like that

Comment: if you want to hunt mosquito with artillery Adobe Photoshop have batch image process option for it s default filters.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I have edited the question, please consider reopening the question.

Comment: I've reopened it.  But it won't stay open for long unless you can focus your question on the specific problem you're having.  See http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/

Comment: Can you more accurately define step 4? Everything else seems fairly trivial.

Comment: @PeteFordham I've added a description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'easiest' solution I can think of is to use the [GraphicsMagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/index.html) library - specifically, the [Magick++](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/index.html) API. With a [Magick::Image](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/Image.html), you can use [Drawable](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/Drawable.html) objects, flood-fills, and even a [Image::swirl](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/Magick++/Image.html#swirl) method. Saving as a PNG can be as simple as a call to `Image::write("filename.png")`